# Azure Powershell Get-AzDataFactory returns an error: The resource type could not be found in the namespace 'Microsoft.DataFactory'

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-powershell

I was using a powershell console inside Azure to run this commandlet:

```
Get-AzDataFactory -ResourceGroupName "rg-name"
```

I get this error message below:

```
Get-AzDataFactory: HTTP Status Code: NotFound
Error Code: InvalidResourceType
Error Message: The resource type could not be found in 
the namespace 'Microsoft.DataFactory' for api version '2015-10-01'.
Request Id: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
Timestamp (Utc):05/11/2021 17:22:11
```

What does this message mean and how do I fix the problem?

Comment: Are you on the most recent Az Powershell? Also, is your Data Factory V1 or V2? If it's V2, you'll need `Get-AzDataFactoryV2`.

Comment: Looks like Get-AZDataFactoryV2 works.  I'm on Powershell version 7.1.3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on your version of Azure Data Factory. If your Azure Data Factory is v1, you should use this command `Get-AzDataFactory -ResourceGroupName "rg-name"`. If it's v2, you need to use `Get-AZDataFactoryV2 -ResourceGroupName "rg-name"`.